# Best jquery css selector to find a colspan of table in IE

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to find the colspan of table cells in IE, but only where the colspan is other than 1. This is the selector I'm using, but there must be a better way. How can I do this?

```
if (isIE) {
   selector = "> tbody > tr > td[colspan*='0'],> tbody > tr > td[colspan*='11'],> tbody > tr > td    [colspan*='2'],> tbody > tr > td[colspan*='3'],> tbody > tr > td[colspan*='4'],> tbody > tr >     td[colspan*='5'],> tbody > tr > td[colspan*='6'],> tbody > tr > td[colspan*='7'],> tbody > tr     > td[colspan*='8'],> tbody > tr > td[colspan*='9']"
   isSpanned = $(tbl).find(selector).length > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [attributename*="val"]
```

This selector represents an element with the "attributename" attribute whose value contains at least one instance of the substring "val". [Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/attribute_selector/attribute%2a%3Dvalue)

Looking at your code I see that you are looking if `<td>` has attribute `colspan`, so do it like this:

```
selector = "table tr td[colspan]"
```

`table` doesn't have a `colspan` attribute, only `th` and `td`

**EDIT**

Take a look at this [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ie7-setting-colspan-as-attribute), maybe this will solve your problem.

Example how you can do:

```
 $("table tr td").each(function(i) { 
    isSpanned = this.colSpan > 1 ?true:false;
 });
```

Comment: IE is always returning colspan for td, even if you not specified..i.e my problem.. So i written like this..Any other way to find if a table has colspan td

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for table cells with `colspan` set to anything but 1. So all you really need is the [attribute-not-equal selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) in jQuery:

```
selector = '> tbody > tr > td[colspan!="1"]'
```

If you want this to work in non-IE browsers, where not every `td` has a `colspan`, you can use `td[colspan][colspan!="1"]` to force the presence of a `colspan` attribute.

Tested on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmorgan123/69qw9/